# C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'student' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, class

I really dont know why im getting the error but then again im not too good at this, right now im just trying to figure out why im not able to print out my records array. Think anyone will be able to point me in the right direction? its not close to being done so its a bit rough...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 


using namespace std;

class student
{
private:
    int id, grade;
    string firstname, lastname;

public:
    student();
    student(int sid, string firstn, string lastn, int sgrade);
    void print(student* records, int size);
};

void main()
{
    string report="records.txt";
    int numr=0 , sid = 0,sgrade = 0;
    string firstn,lastn;

    student *records=new student[7];
    student stu;
    student();

    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;

    in.open(report);
    in>>numr;

    for(int i=0; i>7; i++)
    {
        in>>sid>>firstn>>lastn>>sgrade;
        records[i]=student(sid, firstn,lastn,sgrade);
    }

    in.close();

    stu.print(records, numr);

    system("pause");
}

student::student()
{
}

student::student(int sid, string firstn, string lastn, int sgrade)
{
    id=sid;
    firstname=firstn;
    lastname=lastn;
    grade=sgrade;

}

void student::print(student* records, int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i>7; i++)
        cout<<records[i]<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly.

Comment: oh yeah btw you have a memory leak in there

Comment: void student::print(student* records, int size)
    {
        for(int i=0; i>7; i++)
            cout<<records[i]<< endl;

    }

Comment: Have you overloaded `operator<<` for `student` at all?

Comment: @user1877946 Yes, I can see where the error occurs, but what I mean is your indentation. It's very hard to read code that isn't properly indented.

Comment: im new here not too sure how everything works yet.

Comment: It's nothing to do with how things work. What I mean is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: i always end up cleaning that at the end, bad habit have to get out of it.

Comment: And i>7 should be i<7. Twice.

Answer (score 8):

Unlike languages like Java, C++ doesn't provide a default way to print something. In order to use `cout` you have to do 1 of 2 things:

1. Provide an implicit conversion to something printable (Don't do this)
2. Overload the << operator like so:

   ```
   ostream& operator <<(ostream& str, const student& printable){
       //Do stuff using the printable student and str to print and format
       //various pieces of the student object
       return str;
       //return the stream to allow chaining, str << obj1 << obj2
   }
   ```